# Set background color dynamically in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, background-color, react-props

I´m creating a weather application where I want the background color to change dynamically based on weather conditions fetched from OpenWeatherMaps API. However, I´m not really sure how to do this since I get an error message that says: **"Undefined is not an object (near '...}]color...')**

Right now I´ve pre-defined the conditions in a separate file called WeatherConditions, and I want the props in my Weather file to determine the background color. How can I do this?

**This is my render method in the Weather file. The problem lies in the first view tag after return:**

```
 render() {
    const {
        weatherCondition,
        city,
        country,
        temperature,
        placeholder,
        weatherDescription,
        getWeather,
        handleTextChange,
        searchedCity
    } = this.props;
    const {
        weatherContainer,
        headerContainer,
        tempText,
        tempContainer,
        bodyContainer,
        inputContainer,
        textInputStyle,
        subtitle,
        title
    } = styles;

    return (
        <View
            style={[
                weatherContainer,
                {
                    backgroundColor:
                        weatherConditions[{ weatherCondition }].color
                }
            ]}
        >
            {" "}
            // Does not work right now.
            <View style={headerContainer}>
                <Text style={tempText}>
                    {" "}
                    {city} {country}
                </Text>
                <Text style={tempContainer}>
                    {" "}
                    {Math.round(temperature)}
                    ˚C
                </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={bodyContainer}>
                <View style={inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={textInputStyle}
                        onChangeText={searchedCity =>
                            handleTextChange(searchedCity)
                        }
                        onSubmitEditing={() => getWeather()}
                        placeholder={placeholder}
                        clearTextOnFocus={true}
                        enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
                    />
                </View>
                <Text style={title}>{weatherCondition}</Text>
                <Text style={subtitle}>{weatherDescription}</Text>
            </View>
            {this.renderLoading()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

**My WeatherCondition file:**

```
export const weatherConditions = {

Thunderstorm: {
color: '#303952'
},

Drizzle: {
color: '#8aacb8'
},

Rain: {
color: '#786fa6'
},

Snow: {
color: '#00d8d6'
},

Atmosphere: {
color: '#ff5252'
},

Clear: {
color: '#f5cd79'
},

Clouds: {
color: '#0be881'
},


}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out the problem. I get an undefined error message because the background color renders before my API request is done where the weatherCondition is fetched. Is there a simple way of somehow delaying the render of the background color until the weatherCondition is fetched?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
<View style={[weatherContainer, {
  backgroundColor: weatherConditions[weatherCondition].color
}]}>
```

Note the syntax `weatherConditions[weatherCondition].color`, you don't need any curly brackets.

`weatherConditions` is an object, `weatherCondition` is variable. To access property by variable name, you use bracket notation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this generated a new error message stating "undefined is not an object (evaluating '-WeatherConditions.weatherConditions[weatherCondition].color')".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that weatherCondition is rendered correctly at ***<Text style={title}>{weatherCondition}</Text>*** but it doesn't seem to work when I want to use it to set the background color.